# Hide a Menu Item on Login

Tags: plugins, menus, css, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using the following code to hide a menu item when a customer is not logged and show it when a customer is logged in.

```
.hide-item-not-login{
display: none !important;
}

.logged-in .hide-item-not-login{
display: block !important;
}
```

I applied the class `hide-item-not-login` to my menu item and it works fine.

What I actually want is the opposite. I want the menu item to hide when user logs in and show up when the user (cutsomer in woocommerce) is not logged in.

What changes are suggested? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you change CSS rules?

```
.hide-item-not-login{
    display: block !important;
}

.logged-in .hide-item-not-login{
    display: none !important;
}
```

**EDIT**

To add login/logout menu item, you will need to add one more class to logout menu item. Let's say you added class `.logout-link` to logout menu item.
Then you can add css like this.

```
.hide-item-not-login{
    display: block !important;
}

.logged-in .hide-item-not-login{
    display: none !important;
}

.logout-link{
    display: none !important;
}

.logged-in .logout-link{
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help you on this. :)

Comment: So these are predefined classes in wordpress that will work almost everywhere, right?

Comment: Yes, WordPress adds many useful body and post classes so you can style your website without editing theme PHP files. For your example WordPress added a class in body `logged-in` if a user is logged in. You can check more body_classes here. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all that info. Just one last query, what if I have a case where I want to  hide a menu item say LOGIN and show another item say LOGOUT upon login and vice versa upon logout? How can I use these classes for both menu items?

Comment: See edits in above.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by having the `display: none;` only on the `.logged-in` selector. Like this...

```
.logged-in .hide-item-not-login {
    display: none;
}
```

You might want to change that `.hide-item-not-login` to a more accurate `.hide-item-login` or something to make it more clear for this changed use case. Though it makes no difference to the functionality of it.